# Navigation in restricted area Java EE on Glassfish 4.1

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jaas, jdbcrealm

I am developing a webapp based on Java EE 7 on Glassfish 4.1. I'm new to this environment and I followed some guides to create a JDBC Realm based authentication.

I have only one user role (named USER) that should be able to access all the XHTML pages in the /user folder.

The problem is that when the user logs in, he is redirected to his personal homepage (until now everything is fine), but if I add any link to another page in the same /user folder I still have to login again! Also if I refresh the user's homepage I still have to login.

How is it possible to resolve this problem? Am I missing something?

Here is some code you may find useful to help me:

*web.xml*

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myJdbcRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginErr.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Logged User</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
</security-role>
```

*glassfish-web.xml*

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
    <group-name>USER</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

*login.xhtml*

```
<h:form style="width: 500px; margin: auto; ">
    <p:panel header="Login Form">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="loginGrid">
            <p:outputLabel for="usernameInput" value="Username"/>
            <p:inputText id="usernameInput" value="#{loginBean.username}" 
                         required="false" />
            <p:outputLabel for="passwordInput" value="Password"/>
            <p:password id="passwordInput" value="#{loginBean.password}" 
                        required="false" />
            <p:commandButton value="Login" 
                             action="#{loginBean.login()}" update="loginGrid" />

            <p:messages/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

*LoginBean.java*

```
public String login() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    try {
        request.login(this.username, this.password);
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        MessageBean.addError("Login failed");
        return NavigationBean.toLogin();
    }
    return "/user/home?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Comment: It appears that it has to do something with the request you made during login. Since you are forwarding (not redirecting), that request is still alive after you get to the restricted area after successful login. Try redirecting from the `login()` method after successful login instead of forwarding/dispatching the request (`response.sendRedirect("HomePageLocation")` or append `?faces-redirect=true` to the navigation outcome).

Comment: I tried to do that but the only thing that changes is that now, when I log in, I am redirected to user/home.xhtml (before the url didn't change after login), but, unfortunately, when I click a link to another page in /user I am still redirected to the login form...

Comment: Does this method `request.isUserInRole("USER")` return true after you made a login attempt? You may put a statement like `System.out.println("Is User = "+request.isUserInRole("USER"));` just before the last `return` statement in the `login()` method to verify it.

Comment: It returns false... what does it mean?

Comment: I added this in web.xml:
    <security-role>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>
...now it returns true, but I still have the same problem :(

Comment: It should mean that the role "USER" was not found in the request. This justifies why you're redirected everytime to the login page when targeting restricted area based on USER role.

Comment: Ok, now I added that role in web.xml and returs true... but I still have the problem

Comment: What about making a clean/build & deploy for the project ?

Comment: Done but nothing :( I also restarted the server

Comment: When I move to another page, this message appears on the server's output: SELECT EMAIL, PASSWORD, NAME [...] FROM USER WHERE (EMAIL = ?)
 bind => [1 parameter bound]
does the "?" mean that it has lost the username (email)? How is it possible?

Comment: If this method `request.isUserInRole("USER")` returns true then, that user is considered to be authenticated with the authority/role name `USER`. Do you have some filters or something else in your application that might unintentionally/inadvertently be redirecting to the login page? Can you access pages from the restricted area without login? Once you redirected to the home page after successful login and you refresh the home page, you get back the login page. Can you access pages from the restricted area afterwards? (if you enter the home page URL in the address bar, is that page returned?)

Comment: This should not be a matter but this tag `<context-root>/YourAppRoot</context-root>` appears to be missing in `glassfish-web.xml`. Can you try adding it to that file?

Comment: Sorry if I answer only now, but I've been very busy in these days... anyway in my glassfish-web.xml I have already the context root and I resolved my problem changing the JSF component that I use for the Logout. Thank you everyone